# Edit legend using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts, legend

I copied chart (this chart with legend I prepared in excel) from excel to .ppt (below code). How can I change/edit legend.Top and legend.size?

My code is not working...

```
Sub pptfromexcel()
    Dim pptapp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptppt As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim pptsld As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim shp As Object
    Set chart1 = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
    'Dane do wykresów
    Set d5 = Sheets("Wykresy").Range("Q32:S40")
    Set d6 = Sheets("Wykresy").Range("Q47:S51")

    Set v1PK = Sheets("Wykresy").Range("G7:G7")
    Set v1PM = Sheets("Wykresy").Range("G8:G8")

    Set pptapp = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set pptppt = pptapp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\ppt.pptx")
    pptapp.Visible = True
    pptapp.Activate

    Set pptsld2 = pptppt.Slides(2)


    chart1.Copy
    Set chart1a = pptsld2.Shapes.PasteSpecial

    With chart1a
        .Height = 132
        .Width = 157
        .Left = 26.1
        .Top = 120
        .haslegend=true
        .legend.size = 12
        .legend.top = 150
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When you say your code isn't working - where does it stop working and what message does it give?  Have a read of [ask].

Comment: It looks like you haven't got `Option Explicit` at the top of your module - so it could be a simple misspelled variable name that's stop the code working.  I'm guessing `chart1a` is not a chart - so it won't have a `legend` property as shown by `haslegend` and `legend` hasn't capitalised to `HasLegend` and `Legend`.

Answer (score 1):

The first four properties your are setting are generic properties for all shapes. The legend properties are specific for a chart. The first thing that must happen is that it is pasted as an Excel object. If that is the case, you have a Chart property on your shape and you can do like this:

```
With chart1a
    .Height = 132
    .Width = 157
    .Left = 26.1
    .Top = 120
    .Chart.HasLegend = True
    .Chart.Legend.Size = 12
    .Chart.Legend.Top = 150
End With
```